# Firebase hosted Angular app with ASP.NET Core backend but how to connect to my backend

Tags: angular, visual-studio, firebase, asp.net-core

I learn Angular and have this client app that works on localhost. Backend ASP.NET uses a simple books.xml file as a databas and all Crud calls from the app to ASP.NET `Controller` works grate on localhost(my computer).

I upload the app to Firebase and can access it but of course now the app cant search my books.xml at my backend. How do I configure the app to connect to ASP.NET Core backend here on my computer where the databas is, or the Crud endpoint so to speak. What should I do in this situation?

I know I can upload the books.xml to Firebase Storage and the app can access it but that´s not the point with my project.

Comment: Your ASP.NET Core on your computer? Unless you want to expose your computer to the public by opening firewall ports etc. I'd advise not to do this. You need a host to host your ASP.NET Core.

Comment: You need to upload your backend to a server and then point any reference from localhost to the server in the Angular client.